# How to add data validation to a cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to  add "data validation" in a cell(which is variable) using VBA and the range which is to come in the  data validation list is also variable. Till now I have been using this

Here "range1" is the range which is to come in the data validation list and "rng" is the cell where I want the data validation

```
Dim range1, rng As range
Set range1 = range("a1:a5")
Set rng = range("b1")
With rng
With .Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="range1"
End With
End With
```

I am getting "application defined and object defined error"

Also can someone explain me the meaning of different arguments in

```
With .Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="range1"
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use this one:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim range1 As Range, rng As Range
'change Sheet1 to suit
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set range1 = ws.Range("A1:A5")
Set rng = ws.Range("B1")

With rng.Validation
    .Delete 'delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & range1.Address
End With
```

Note that when you're using `Dim range1, rng As range`, only `rng` has type of `Range`, but `range1` is `Variant`. That's why I'm using `Dim range1 As Range, rng As Range`.
About meaning of parameters you can read is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840078%28v=office.15%29.aspx), but in short:

- `Type:=xlValidateList` means validation type, in that case you should select value from list
- `AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop` specifies the icon used in message boxes displayed during validation. If user enters any value out of list, he/she would get error message.
- in your original code, `Operator:= xlBetween` is odd. It can be used only if two formulas are provided for validation.
- `Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & range1.Address` for list data validation provides address of list with values (in format `=Sheet!A1:A5`)

Comment: Hey I did the changes and its working just fine, thanks for help<br/>                                                                Hey can you please explain <br/>'     <Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & range1.Address> '<br/> again in a little detail, I just don't undersatnd what is   "='"  and   "=!"  ,I am new to VBA, please don't mind or if you have any link where I can study it in detail will be awesome.

Comment: @Gajju, no worry, it's easy:) lets start! desired result is something like this: `Formula1:="='Sheet1'!A1:A5"` - All formulas in excel starts from equal sign: `=`. Next, `'Sheet1'!` means that range `A1:A5` belongs to sheet `Sheet1` (if your sheet name _doesn't_ contain spaces, you can ommit sigh `'` like this: Formula1:="=Sheet1!A1:A5". But we don't want to hardcode this formula, so we use: `Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & range1.Address` where `ws.Name` returns sheet name (e.g. "Sheet1") and `range1.Address` returns `A1:A5`.

Comment: Hey it was easy to understand, thanks for the time and thanks again for the help...

Comment: A quick addition to this great answer: in case you want to add a list of values which is not a range of cells, you must specify a list of comma-separated values as `Formula1` parameter. For instance, if you want to constrain the content of the cell to contain one of the letters A, B or C, the code to be used is `Formula1:="A,B,C"`

Comment: @DmitryPavliv.how to apply the same operation to sequence of rows.i.e, row b1,b2,b3....Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If you get confused with setting the options of data validation, I will suggest "recording" a macro and diving into the codes there. For example, I just complete a sub to configure data validation for cells in a batch. Find the requirements and codes below.
[image][image][image]

```
Sub setCellDataValidation(idxRow As LongLong)
' column B
With Cells(idxRow, 2).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="E,PE,DE"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Input Format"
    .InputMessage = "E/PE/DE"
    .ErrorMessage = "Only E, PE, and DE allowed."
    .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
' column D
With Cells(idxRow, 4).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="0", Formula2:="100"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Input Format"
    .InputMessage = "Integer in 0 - 100"
    .ErrorMessage = "Only Integer in 0 - 100 allowed."
    .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
' column E
With Cells(idxRow, 5).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="1/1/2022", Formula2:="12/31/2024"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Input Format"
    .InputMessage = "yyyy-mm-dd in 2022/1/1 to 2024/12/31"
    .ErrorMessage = "Only yyyy-mm-dd in 2022/1/1 to 2024/12/31 allowed."
    .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
' column F
With Cells(idxRow, 6).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateTime, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="00:00:00", Formula2:="23:59:59"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Time Format"
    .InputMessage = "hh:mm in 00:00:00 to 23:59:59"
    .ErrorMessage = "Only hh:mm in 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 allowed."
    .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
' column W
With Cells(idxRow, 23).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="0.01", Formula2:="2000.99"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Input Format"
    .InputMessage = "3 decimal"
    .ErrorMessage = "Only 3 decimal allowed."
    .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```