# Data Validation to the two different Worksheets using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have sheet1 with data,

Each field should refer the other sheet fields(Sheet2) for validation

in Sheet2, Data Validation list,

[Data validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSb8x.jpg)

```
Sub validation()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

'Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets("Data Validation")
'Set ws3 = Sheets("V011 Record")


Dim wkst As Excel.Worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="listdata", RefersTo:= _
                       "=Data Validation!$A$1:$A$4"

For Each wkst In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If wkst.Name <> "Data Validation" Then
        
        With wkst.Range("A1").Validation

            .Delete
            

            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, 
Operator:= _
                 xlBetween, Formula1:="=listdata"

        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

PLEASE NOTE:
Sheet1 Name: Dynamic name
Sheet2 Name: "Data Validation"

Can anyone help me pls

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: @BigBen in the line  .Apptype, it is throwing error as application or with object ....

Comment: You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956604/how-to-add-data-validation-to-a-cell-using-vba). Almost an exact duplicate of this question, even down to your use of `xlBetween`, which you don't need for a list :-)

Comment: @BigBen the reference you shared is that they worked around single sheet, in my case it is two sheets to play

Comment: Nice try! Your problem isn't with 2 sheets, it's with your `Formula1` reference. You need to reference the `Data Validation` sheet, as well as the `listdata` `Address`. Or just use `Formula1:="='Data Validation'!$A$1:$A$4"`

Comment: @BigBen Perfect!!! But in this, wt about the other field validations... B1:B7, C1:C5 ...so on...I hope we can use increment method to check...Can you please help me on this

Comment: You already have a `With... End With` section for Column A -  you can use that same structure for each remaining Column.

Comment: In my example, in the sheet2 Data Validation, we have shared $A$1:$A$4" in the code...what about if there is many list to validations??, How could I change the lastrow to get automatically

Comment: Google "vba get last row" - thousands of people have had this problem before you :-). You need to generalize your code - i.e. you need to loop through each column, finding the last row each time, and then adding validation to your other sheet similarly to how you are doing currently.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen One last question, I would like to use if condition to check whether the value(in the "A1") in sheet1 should be in the range (A1:A4). 
Can you help me pls

Comment: How to change this Formula1:="='Data Validation'!$A$1:$A$4" into incremental way?

Comment: Check out the question I mentioned earlier. Use a `Range` to refer to the list in each column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add data validation to a cell using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956604/how-to-add-data-validation-to-a-cell-using-vba)