# Data validation in excel for ssn, first name, last name, email address not working

Tags: regex, excel-formula, ms-office

I am trying to build a regex in Excel;s data validation. However, it is not working.

Would you please explain how could I put data validation in Excel

I want last name data validation with characters, quote('), space and dot.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("^[a-zA-Z\s,.']*$",F:F,0))
```

I am using above formula and, again, it is not working

For SSN, I am using following formula and it is not working

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH("/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/",A2,0)),LEFT(A2,1)>=0)
```

Please help me to build data validation from data tab or VBA script for the data validation.

Answer (score 2):

The [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A) function in Excel is not used for regex matching.
But you do not need it here, it looks like.

To allow only letters and `,.'` you could use formula like this:

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)," ,.'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))
```

To validate an SSN try the formula from the guide [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5318-excel-data-validation-ssn.html)

```
=AND(LEFT(F1,1)>="0",LEN(F1)<10,ISNUMBER(F1))
```

---

Some more pointers:

- More [Data Validation examples](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3408-excel-only-allow-alphanumeric.html)
- Adding validation to a cell using VBA is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22956899/8291949) and [using Regex in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956604/how-to-add-data-validation-to-a-cell-using-vba) here, as noted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [Match Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) is not able to support regex. It can only match a single, constant value.

I suggest you take a look at [This very detailed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops), which explains beautifully how to use Regular Expressions in Excel.

Other than that, your Regular Expression looks to be in working order - if you get this set up, it should work immediately. Good luck!